# Selenium click on tabbed element

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-chromedriver

The issue I am having is in clicking the description. The very first element, it can manage to click the summary for the very first element. However for every subsequent book it fails to click the summary. I have tried javascript, It does not manage to click anything!

Attached below is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By 
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options = options)
driver.get('https://carverlib.ent.sirsi.net/client/en_US/default/search/results?qf=ITYPE%09Material+Type%091%3AADULT-BOOK%09Adult+Book&av=0&isd=true')
for i in range(0,12):
    try:
        print("Clicking on element "+ str(i))
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(f'//*[@id="detailLink{i}"]').click()
        print("Located element")
        print("The title is "+WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, f'//*[@id="detail_biblio{i}"]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]'))).text)
        print("The isbn is "+WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, f'//*[@id="detail_biblio{i}"]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]'))).text)
        WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a[href="#tabs-4"]'))).click()
        print("The description is "+WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="tabs-4"]/div[1]/p'))).text)
        driver.execute_script("""document.querySelectorAll('[title="Close"]')[document.querySelectorAll('[title="Close"]').length - 1].click();""")
        print("Closed element")
    except:
       WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(lambda x: x.execute_script("""return document.querySelectorAll('[title="Close"]')[0]"""))
       driver.execute_script("""document.querySelectorAll('[title="Close"]')[document.querySelectorAll('[title="Close"]').length - 1].click();""")
```

Here is a screenshot of the website in question.

[image: Library website]

Comment: After debugging, I have found the line WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a[href="#tabs-4"]'))).click() causes a timeout exception. Interestingly there are multiple a[href="#tabs-4"] on the page, and they increase as more books are opened. I have no idea how to select a specific a[href="#tabs-4"] in the WebDriverWait and this is causing the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some code that does work.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By 
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options = options)
driver.get('https://carverlib.ent.sirsi.net/client/en_US/default/search/results?qf=ITYPE%09Material+Type%091%3AADULT-BOOK%09Adult+Book&av=0&isd=true')
for i in range(0,12):
    try:
        print("Clicking on element "+ str(i))
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(f'//*[@id="detailLink{i}"]').click()
        print("Located element")
        print("The title is "+WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, f'//*[@id="detail_biblio{i}"]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]'))).text)
        print("The isbn is "+WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, f'//*[@id="detail_biblio{i}"]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]'))).text)
        WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a[href="#tabs-4"]'))).click() # for the first element
        print("The description is "+WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="tabs-4"]/div[1]/p'))).text)
        driver.execute_script("""document.querySelectorAll('[title="Close"]')[document.querySelectorAll('[title="Close"]').length - 1].click();""")
        print("Closed element")
    except:
       summaryList = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('a[href="#tabs-4"]')
       summaryList[len(summaryList) - 1].click()
       Desc = ""
       paragraphText = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.enrichedContentElement")[i].find_elements_by_tag_name("p")
       for element in paragraphText:
           Desc = element.text + Desc
       print(Desc)
       WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(lambda x: x.execute_script("""return document.querySelectorAll('[title="Close"]')[0]"""))
      driver.execute_script("""document.querySelectorAll('[title="Close"]')[document.querySelectorAll('[title="Close"]').length - 1].click();""")
```

Essentially the web driver wait does not work when there are multiple matching elements.